# Create DataTemplate in codebehind

Tags: c#, wpf, dynamic, datatemplate, code-behind

How do i add controls to datatemplates programmatically?

For Example. Below I've created TextBlock and DataTemplate.

```
TextBlock text = new TextBlock();
DataTemplate template = new DataTemplate();
```

Now I need to add TextBlock to DataTemplate. How to achieve this?

I know that there are other ways of addind data template in code behind
1. create a data template in XAML and load it on code behind
2. create and add using XamlParser

but i need to do in the way i showed in example.

Need some help.

Answer (score 43):

Although [Archedius's method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5592399/3834) works, officially it is deprecated and instead recommended way to programmatically create a template is to load XAML from a string or a memory stream using the Load method of the XamlReader class like this...

```
public DataTemplate Create(Type type)
{
    StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(
    @"<DataTemplate 
        xmlns=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation""> 
            <" + type.Name + @" Text=""{Binding " + ShowColumn + @"}""/> 
        </DataTemplate>");
    XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(stringReader);
    return XamlReader.Load(xmlReader) as DataTemplate;
}
```

Official line taken from msdn: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelementfactory.aspx

Code example from Fredrik Hedblad's post here: [Problems with XamlReader generating DataTemplate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7170937/problems-with-xamlreader-generating-datatemplate#answer-7171332)

Comment: Use the XamlReader in System.Windows.Markup NOT System.Xaml

Comment: Obsolete as the other option might be, this is a *very* inconvenient method, not only it provides virtually no static error checking and the produced error messages are cryptic (e.g. unexpected charater 0x20 at line 5 position 27), moreover it also means you have no access to project's resources. IMHO stay away from this for anthing but simplest templates.

Comment: Hard to call the alternative a deprecated approach when the `DataTemplate.VisualTree` method is the one that is still used internally in WPF to create templates programmatically.

Answer (score 40):

You have first to declare a DataTemplate:

```
DataTemplate template = new DataTemplate { DataType = typeof(< Type of the object the template refers>) };
```

Then declare a layout panel like StackPanel in this way

```
FrameworkElementFactory stackPanelFactory = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(StackPanel));
stackPanelFactory.SetValue(StackPanel.OrientationProperty, Orientation.Vertical);
```

and finally attach the TextBlock piece at it:

```
FrameworkElementFactory title = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(TextBlock));
title.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, new Binding("< name of your binding >"));
stackPanelFactory.AppendChild(title);
```

in order to display the StackPanel created in this way you have to attach it to the VisualTree:

```
template.VisualTree = stackPanelFactory;
```

Hope it helps! :)

Answer (score 18):

I know it is an work-around, but I published a tip in code project (http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/808808/Create-Data-and-Control-Templates-using-Delegates) that allows you to create a data-template using a delegate.
For example:

```
TemplateGenerator.CreateDataTemplate(() => new TextBox());
```

This will be enough to create a datatemplate that creates a new textbox. If you want a binding too, it could be written like:

```
TemplateGenerator.CreateDataTemplate
(
  () =>
  {
    var result = new TextBox();
    result.SetBinding(TextBox.TextProperty, "PathForTheBinding");
    return result;
  }
);
```

The code of the TemplateGenerator is the following:

```
/// <summary>
/// Class that helps the creation of control and data templates by using delegates.
/// </summary>
public static class TemplateGenerator
{
  private sealed class _TemplateGeneratorControl:
    ContentControl
  {
    internal static readonly DependencyProperty FactoryProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Factory", typeof(Func<object>), typeof(_TemplateGeneratorControl), new PropertyMetadata(null, _FactoryChanged));

    private static void _FactoryChanged(DependencyObject instance, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    {
      var control = (_TemplateGeneratorControl)instance;
      var factory = (Func<object>)args.NewValue;
      control.Content = factory();
    }
  }

  /// <summary>
  /// Creates a data-template that uses the given delegate to create new instances.
  /// </summary>
  public static DataTemplate CreateDataTemplate(Func<object> factory)
  {
    if (factory == null)
      throw new ArgumentNullException("factory");

    var frameworkElementFactory = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(_TemplateGeneratorControl));
    frameworkElementFactory.SetValue(_TemplateGeneratorControl.FactoryProperty, factory);

    var dataTemplate = new DataTemplate(typeof(DependencyObject));
    dataTemplate.VisualTree = frameworkElementFactory;
    return dataTemplate;
  }

  /// <summary>
  /// Creates a control-template that uses the given delegate to create new instances.
  /// </summary>
  public static ControlTemplate CreateControlTemplate(Type controlType, Func<object> factory)
  {
    if (controlType == null)
      throw new ArgumentNullException("controlType");

    if (factory == null)
      throw new ArgumentNullException("factory");

    var frameworkElementFactory = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(_TemplateGeneratorControl));
    frameworkElementFactory.SetValue(_TemplateGeneratorControl.FactoryProperty, factory);

    var controlTemplate = new ControlTemplate(controlType);
    controlTemplate.VisualTree = frameworkElementFactory;
    return controlTemplate;
  }
}
```

And it has a method for ControlTemplates too.

Comment: This is by far the best answer, works also with complex DataTemplates - where the other two answers failed