# How to add icon and text in ListviewControl for windows form application

Tags: wpf, listview, wpf-controls

I have a windows form  application in which I need to use Listview control from WPF. I am trying to add Icon and text in a list view, it is a view of completed or failed tasks with some text. I cannot use xaml so need to so it programatically. I am doing following

this.listViewComponents.Items.Add(new MyObject(Properties.Resources.Failed,"Failed"));

in the final listview, i see only assembly name and do not see Icon followed by "Failed" text. Am I missing someting?. Please help !!!

Answer (score 0):

You need a DataTemplate in the WPF project for your `MyObject` class.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521.aspx

Comment: msdn link talks about creating DataTemplate using XAML, however I cannot use xaml, is there way to do the same in code behind?

Comment: I definitely wouldn't recommend creating the DataTemplate in code, but it can be done - http://stackoverflow.com/a/5592399/503969