# How to bind a class to WPF AutoCompleteBox?

Tags: c#, wpf, autocomplete

I've got a class like this:

```
class MyClass
{
    public int ID{ get; set; }
    public string Title{ get; set; }
}
```

Currently I'm binding it to AutoCompleteBox like this:

```
List<MyClass> lstMyClass = new List<MyClass>();
lstMyClass = context.Sometable;
autoCompleteBox1.ItemsSource = lstMyClass;
autoCompleteBox1.ValueMemberPath = "Title";
autoCompleteBox1.PopulateComplete();
```

It finds the objects by the title, but in autocomplete part it shows the class definition instead of the items title. Any idea?

Comment: You are creating a new list, then throwing it away by overwriting it with `context.Sometable`. You can just assign the value of `ItemsSource` with `context.Sometable` directly.

Comment: @DrewNoakes this piece of code is just a sample im doing exactly what ur sayin, anyway the problem is the **`autocomplete`** part as i've mentioned, not the lists content.

Comment: Check the API for other *MemberPath properties. I'm not familiar with it myself.

Comment: @DrewNoakes already done it, theres nothing like `DisplayMemberPath`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `ItemTemplate` ([msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.autocompletebox.itemtemplate%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)).

```
<controls:AutoCompleteBox x:Name="autoCompleteBox1"        
      FilterMode="Contains"              
      IsTextCompletionEnabled="True">
    <controls:AutoCompleteBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </controls:AutoCompleteBox.ItemTemplate>
</controls:AutoCompleteBox>
```

Comment: It's great, tnx, can I add ItemTemplate programmaticlay? don't want any xaml code. if its possible it would be fantastic.

Comment: @MehdiGhanavatian you should define your GUI in XAML, not in code-behind. But if you want to do that, check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5471405/create-datatemplate-in-code-behind

Comment: I define GUI in xaml, i want to be able to customize everything. thats why i wanna add details in code-behind.

Answer (score 1):

You can override ToString() method in MyClass , so that it will return Title.

Comment: the class comes from entityframework, but it was a good point.

Comment: Well, if you can't change the class, you can wrap it in another class, and override ToString() there. Not sure that this is the nicest solution, though.