# Binding to the ItemSource

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'm trying to build dynamically a AutoCompleteBox. Then I want to use a list of Clients in my itemsource, and the user visualize the DescClient field.

```
List<Client> clients = ClientAction.getClientsFromUsers(Environment.UserName);
(field as AutoCompleteBox).ItemsSource = clients;

//CLIENT MEMBERS
    private int idClient;
            private string descClient;
            private int idGroup;
            private User user;
```

Already tried like:

```
(field as AutoCompleteBox).ValueMemberPath = "DescClient"
```

But doesn't show anything. Am I doing something wrong afecting the ValueMemberPath or should I use another Proprety?

Comment: Do  you have properties defined for the client members?

Comment: Just a note, you should better write `((AutoCompleteBox)field)` instead of `(field as AutoCompleteBox)`, because in case `field` is not an AutoCompleteBox it would correctly throw an InvalidCastException, instead of a NullReferenceException.

Comment: Yes I have my propretie "DescField" to access the variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15465638/how-to-bind-a-class-to-wpf-autocompletebox) you can use ItemTemplate (there's also a reference on how to create DataTemplate from code, if you need it).

[here](https://www.jeff.wilcox.name/2008/11/autocompletebox-missing-guide/) a guide on AutoCompleteBox from Jeff Wilcox website.

Comment: I tried that approach, creating my user control with the bindings, but it stays the same

Comment: Right now the list is returning me not the DescField but the full name of Client <namespace>.Client

I guess I'm missing some atribute to display only that field

Comment: Already worked! I had to add ValueMemberPath="DescClient" to controls:AutoCompleteBox. thanks a lot