# How do I create a DataTemplate in code?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin

I'm trying to create a custom cell renderer in Xamarin.  To do so, I need to return a `Windows.UI.Xaml.DataTemplate`.  When I search for how to create one in code, the only documentation I can find is [here](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/How-to-dynamically-875a548e), but that doesn't create the `DataTemplate` in code, it creates some XML and then hands it off to the parser.  How do I create a `DataTemplate` in C#?

Comment: What about this http://stackoverflow.com/a/5592399/734040 ?

Comment: @DecadeMoon no joy, I'm afraid.  When I tried the approach they describe, it didn't work because there's no `DataType` property on `Windows.UI.Xaml.DataTemplate`.

Comment: I also don't see any documentation on doing this via code. However, why do you need to code it in C#? DataTemplates are much easier to create via XAML. You can use a custom renderer with that, explained here: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/custom-renderer/viewcell/#Creating_the_Custom_Renderer_on_Windows_Phone_and_UWP