# How create a template XAML style (code behind) WPF

Tags: wpf

I have this code on my xaml and works fine (ListView component)

```
<ListView.ItemsPanel>
  <ItemsPanelTemplate>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"></StackPanel>
  </ItemsPanelTemplate>
```

I´m trying to replicate on code behind using this answer [Create DataTemplate in code behind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5471405/create-datatemplate-in-code-behind/5592399), but i could not make it work (the Russell´s answer). Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Edit:

```
ListView listView = new ListView();
listView.ItemsPanel = GetItemsPanelTemplate();

private ItemsPanelTemplate GetItemsPanelTemplate()
{
  string xaml = @"<ItemsPanelTemplate   xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation' xmlns:x='http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml'>
                            <ListView.ItemsPanel>
                            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation=""Horizontal""></StackPanel>
                            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            </ListView.ItemsPanel>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>";
  return XamlReader.Parse(xaml) as ItemsPanelTemplate;
}
```

Comment: Show us the code you wrote that doesn't work, and we'll tell you what's wrong with it.

Comment: I edit the question

Comment: You have to actually read the error message... please compare the upper xaml with your code-xaml-string. The latter has `ListView.ItemsPanel` nested within `ItemsPanelTemplate`, which ofcourse doesn't work.

Comment: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, __a specific problem or error__ and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code would work if you stripped out the `ListView.ItemsPanel` element and the inner `ItemsPanelTemplate` element:

```
private ItemsPanelTemplate GetItemsPanelTemplate()
{
    return XamlReader.Parse(
        @"<ItemsPanelTemplate xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation'>
            <StackPanel Orientation='Horizontal' IsItemsHost='True' />
          </ItemsPanelTemplate>") as ItemsPanelTemplate;
}
```

However, the preferred way, based on the answer you linked, would be:

```
private ItemsPanelTemplate GetItemsPanelTemplate()
{
    var factory = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(StackPanel));

    factory.SetValue(StackPanel.OrientationProperty, Orientation.Horizontal);
    factory.SetValue(Panel.IsItemsHostProperty, true);

    return new ItemsPanelTemplate { VisualTree = factory };
}
```

Comment: If i could ask you one more thing...to insert more properties such as alignment and size to this component, how would it be? using this same schema XamlReader, im trying to understand...

Comment: You should only be using `XamlReader` for something that _cannot_ be written equivalently in C#.  Most Xaml code translates cleanly to C#, but templates are a special case.  To change any other property, just change it directly on the instance, e.g., `listView.Width = 250` or `listView.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center`.

Comment: Sure, this make a lot of sense... I understand now, thanks again.