# Is there a way to build a DataTemplate with only C#

Tags: c#, wpf, datatemplate

Is there a way to build a DataTemplate without using the [deprecated](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/deprecated)  `FrameworkElementFactory` or the `XamlReader.Load` method of string interpretation to code [(related question)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/248362/how-do-i-build-a-datatemplate-in-c-sharp-code) or [(another related)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5471405/create-datatemplate-in-code-behind)?

```
DataTemplate dt = new DataTemplate();
StackPanel sp = new StackPanel();
ComboBox cellComboBox = new ComboBox() { Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed };
CheckBox cellCheckBox = new CheckBox() { Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed };

sp.Children.Add(cellComboBox);
sp.Children.Add(cellCheckBox);

// then add the stackpanel somehow?
```

**Update: Why?**
This is for a new program that may have to be supported for years.  XamlReader string parsing at runtime for something that's got a constructor, methods, properties... feels kludgy.  The `FrameworkElementFactory` has been deprecated for several versions but has never had a real replacement.

Answer (score 7):

> Is there a way to build a DataTemplate with only C#

Yes, you use either the `FrameworkElementFactory` or the `XamlReader.Load` method to create a `DataTemplate` programmatically.

> ...without using the deprecated `FrameworkElementFactory` or the `XamlReader.Load` method?

Short answer: No.

Why would you need yet another way when there are two already? Also note that it's perfectly fine to use the `FrameworkElementFactory` class if you don't want to use strings. Despite what the documentation on MSDN says, this type is not really marked as obsolete or deprecated in .NET Framework 4.7.2.

Answer (score 4):

To elaborate on @mm8's answer: no, because if you inspect the [`FrameworkTemplate.LoadContent`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/FrameworkTemplate.cs,284100a9dd5854be) method you'll find that a template is basically a wrapper that uses either a `FrameworkElementFactory` or a `TemplateContent` to load the contents, `TemplateContent` being a utility to read *XAML* node stream. So these are the only two ways in which a template can operate.

Personally, of the two, I'd recommend using *XAML* (as a separate **.xaml* file rather than a `string`), because it's far more readable, but also because `FrameworkElementFactory` has limited functionality, i.e. it only supports dependency properties and routed events (you cannot create a factory that would set a regular *CLR* property or event handler). It has one advantage over *XAML* though - it does support generic classes, so perhaps a mix of the two is the most proper approach.